# Accessing data from Singleton, clarification needed

Tags: objective-c

I have a singleton class `Deck`

[image]

[image]

`Deck` contains a bunch of `Cards`

[image]

Each `Card` knows, about amongst other things, an image assigned to it.

[image]

When the class responsible for displaying the card's image tries to access it .. well it stops here.

[image]

**Why can't i access the faceImage?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you type out `[c faceImage];` and build, do you get (if using ARC) an error like "Receiver type 'Card' for instance message is a forward declaration", or (if not using ARC) a warning like "Instance method '-faceImage' not found (return type defaults to 'id')"?

Did you forward-declare `@class Card` in `Deck.h`?

You probably just need to `#import "Card.h"` in the file where you're trying to access `faceImage`.

Comment: Indeed you are correct. Forgot to `#import Card.h`. Thank you